# joomla 3+ get parameters from module and output them

Tags: joomla

I have tried a few ways to do this but can't get any thing to work. My issue is that I want to pass a parameter from my module to a variable and output it in my html, through the default.php file.

Here is my config in the xml:

```
<config>
 <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
               <field  name="prod_price"
                    type="text"
                    size="50"
                    label="Product Price"
                    description="Enter the product price" />
             </fieldset>
       </fields>    
    </config>
```

I think this is okay as it appears in the back-end.

My mod_helloworld.php file is simple and include a helper.php require, see below:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';
$hello = modHelloWorldHelper::getHello($params);
$mydata = modHelloWorldHelper::getMydata($params);
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_helloworld');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet('modules/mod_helloworld/css/style.css');
$document->addScript('modules/mod_helloworld/js/test.js');
```

I think this is okay, the variables are all returning values.

My helper.php file is as below:

```
class ModHelloWorldHelper
{
    public static function getHello($params)
    {
        return 'Hello, World!'; 
    }
    public static function getMydata($params)
    {
        return 'Hello, World! ';    
    }
}
```

I then echo these variable in my default.php and they output fine. What I think I need to do is to get the $params variable somehow and reference the prod_price but I can't seem to do it. I am a beginner with creating modules so excuse any obvious errors. If the getMyData function could collect the params then I could perhaps output them but I am not sure where to put code?

Kind regards,

James

Comment: If you really want to use your helper class then assign `$params` by reference (`&$params`) and get the params via `JFactory::getApplication()->getParams;`.  I suggest you check core modules (i.e mod_article_latest) or other modules to learn how to get what you want. And btw, there's [Joomla StackExchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

suppose http://examples.com/index.php?prod_price=20

You can receive that data in your module via

```
$price = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('prod_price',0);
```

it will receive post or get request.